# Magento OOB REST API - V1/Search is not returning any items

Tags: php, rest, magento, magento2

I was trying to use the Magento 2 OOB REST API for search.

Request URL as in the below format.

```
<host>/rest/all/V1/search?searchCriteria[requestName]=quick_search_container&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=search_term&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=Life
```

I have products similar to the search query, yet am not getting the items in the search results.

Response as below

```
{
    "items": [],
    "aggregations": {
        "buckets": [
            {
                "name": "category_bucket",
                "values": []
            },
            {
                "name": "color_bucket",
                "values": []
            },
            {
                "name": "material_bucket",
                "values": []
            },
            {
                "name": "size_bucket",
                "values": []
            }
        ],
        "bucket_names": [
            "category_bucket",
            "color_bucket",
            "material_bucket",
            "size_bucket"
        ]
    },
    "search_criteria": {
        "request_name": "quick_search_container",
        "filter_groups": [
            {
                "filters": [
                    {
                        "field": "search_term",
                        "value": "Life",
                        "condition_type": "eq"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "total_count": 0
}
```

Do I need to change some configuration changes. i have done reindexing but its not helping